# In excel, I am trying to use an IF statement and a Vlookup to dynamically multiple items in different sheets within a workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to dynamically associate labour costs in excel using an IF Statement and a Vlookup.
In one sheet(called Labour Cost) I have Location Name and Labour Cost columns and I want the lookup value to be the city and match it with the table array in the other sheet in order to calculate labour costs.

I have used the following formula:

```
=IF(B4=VLOOKUP(B4,'Labour Drivers '!$B$3:$E$8,1,FALSE),'Labour Drivers '!C4*'Labour Drivers '!D4*'Labour Drivers '!E4,0)
```

However this just moves up and down the columns and returns costs based on this. I would like to make it more dynamic so that if the city orders get moved around then the proper wages, hours and employees still return the associated costs per location.

I am not married to using an IF statement and Vlookup, just looking for the best way to do this.

**Labour Cost**

[image: Sheet 1 - Labour Cost]

**Labour Drivers***

[image: Sheet 2 - Labour Drivers]

Comment: Nothing wrong with the used formula,, could you plz explain that what change may spoil the calculation, since data in both sheets are looking organized ! If you are expected to add new data in both Sheets and wanna to automate the job, then you may create DYNAMIC DATA RANGE ! [Just check this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/19/excel-dynamic-named-range/) .

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using `XLOOKUP` in your formula instead of the combination of `IF` and `VLOOKUP`. The formula of the cell `C4` of "Labour Costs" sheet will be.

```
=XLOOKUP(B4,'Labour Drivers'!$B$4:$B$8,'Labour Drivers'!$D$4:$D$8)
```

The formula searches the  value in `B4` on the range from `B4` to `B8` of "Labour Drivers" sheet and return the result from `D4` to `D8` of the same sheet.

2. If XLOOKUP is not available for your version of Excel, try to combine `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions. The formula

```
=INDEX('Labour Drivers'!$D$4:$D$8,MATCH(B4,'Labour Drivers'!$B$5:$B$8,0))
```

Comment: Unfortunately XLOOKUP isnt out for for everyone which sucks. is there anything else you can think of?

Comment: @mbadataguy See edit.